# Acronis backup to offsite

Tags: backup, acronis-trueimage

Is there any simple way to create an offsite backup destination server for Acronis Cyber Protect backup?

- My initial thoughts were to simply setup a docker container running the normal agent (`CyberProtect_AgentForLinux_x86_64.bin`), create a storage location using the cloud/web interface, and set other backup plans to point to that backup location. I soon realized that it wouldn't let me select this new location for other servers' backup plans. Is this correct?

  - https://kb.acronis.com/content/62826
- The next theory is that maybe you have to use the Acronis Storage or Acronis Storage Gateway?

  - https://www.acronis.com/en-us/blog/posts/building-private-cloud-backup-storage/
  - https://kb.acronis.com/content/59435
- Alternatively, I could tunnel the external storage server to be network-visible to the onsite servers, but I would like to maintain separation of networks for security.

Comment: This really needs its own tags, but I don't have enough reputation to create:
acronis, acronis-cyber-protect, acronis-cyber-protect-cloud

Comment: We don’t need 3 Acronis tags one is enough.

Comment: Agreed, any single one I presented would be fine, but "acronis-trueimage" is probably not okay (but the closest to Acronis that currently exists).

Comment: Create the backup locally, and copy it offsite. That way you have *two* copies: one local if the offsite destination goes dark (and the *do*, on occasion) and the other offsite, if something happens at your locale. There are many ways to do this, e.g., with a site that auto-syncs local data. See https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-onedrive/

Answer (score 0):

You grab a separate Linux-running server, you configure StarWind VTL there and make Acronis do periodic fulls to StarWind-managed virtual tapes. StarWind would automate offloading tape images to AWS S3 (Azure, B2 etc) and back. On purpose. We used this approach with pre-V12 Veeam when it couldn’t do S3 itself, and we use it with a free version of Veeam with restricted public cloud access now. Acronis is no different within the context.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/starwind-cloud-vtl-for-aws-and-veeam/